# Desktop application in C# shows notifications only a few times in Windows 10

Tags: c#, windows, desktop-application

So, I made an app in C# that sends a custom toast notification made from the arguments provided. And it works fine in windows 11, and in windows 10 only in my system.

For other users, the notification appears only sometimes, and sometimes it does not appear at all or appears after a long time in the action centre.

Here is the repo for the app:
https://github.com/deathcrafter/Raintoaster

I have tried different versions of .NET Frameworks, including 4.6.1(lowest) and 4.8. Everything seems to work fine for my Windows 10 pc, and users who have Windows 11 insider build running on their pc. But not for other Windows 10 devices.

Can anyone point out to what I am doing wrong, or what may be causing this.

P.S.: I have recently downgraded from Windows 11 to Windows 10 with a clean install, which may be the reason it's working for me.

Thanks in advance,
death.crafter

Extract from the code:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Check if app was activated from toast
        bool m = ToastNotificationManagerCompat.WasCurrentProcessToastActivated();
        if (!m)
        {
            // Parse arguments and create toast
            ParseArguments(args);
        }
        else
        {
            bool done = false;
            Process rainmeter = new Process();

            // Listen to notification activation
            ToastNotificationManagerCompat.OnActivated += toastArgs =>
            {
                // Obtain the arguments from the notification
                ToastArguments ar = ToastArguments.Parse(toastArgs.Argument);

                // Obtain any user input (text boxes, menu selections) from the notification
                ValueSet userInput = toastArgs.UserInput;

                string[] programArgs = ar["arguments"].Split(new string[] { "|" }, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                rainmeter.StartInfo.FileName = programArgs[0];

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in userInput)
                {
                    string arg = pair.Value.ToString();
                    programArgs[1] = programArgs[1].Replace("$" + pair.Key + "$", arg.Replace("\r", "\n"));
                    programArgs[1] = programArgs[1].Replace("$" + pair.Key + ":CRLF$", arg.Replace("\r", "#CRLF#"));
                }

                rainmeter.StartInfo.Arguments = programArgs[1];
                try
                {
                    rainmeter.Start();
                    done = true;
                }
                catch (SystemException exec)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Couldn't start program. Error: " + exec);
                    done = true;
                }
            };

            // Keep the app running until OnActivated event is raised and is completed
            while (!done)
                Thread.Sleep(100);
        }
    }
```